# Jasmine - Running a spec only if a condition is true

Tags: mobile, jasmine, webdriver-io

We are using Jasmine 2 with WebDriverIO to do some web based testing and we want to share the suites between devices / browsers.

This gives us some issues in that some features are disabled on devices so can't be tested and should be skipped. They shouldn't be failed as the feature is not designed to display on that device.

Jasmine has the ability to mark as pending pending() however I can't seem to find a way to do this without wrapping spec's in if statements or manually calling it inside each it.

I need to do this automatically so manually marking the specs or suites is not a good option.

Example the below would only want to run on a desktop not a mobile device

```
it('shows the product on the checkout', () => {
expect(map.items.getText()).toEqual('1 Item);
});
```

Comment: I have looked at grep to lock on a word or start by name but it just seems to make a mess of the specs naming and could easily miss fire.

I'm strongly against maintaining multiple versions of the same scripts for different environments or browsers as keeping in sync is likely to prove impossible.

Comment: You can override the done or the timeout value as suggested for other solutions but doesn't seem clean to do these.

Currently settling on just calling a function with a flag to mark as pending() if the criteria matches